# TypeScript: Defining constructor of parent class which is aware of child class's properties

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

```js
abstract class Parent {
  public foo: string;

  constructor(v: Partial<Parent>) {
    Object.assign(this, v);
  }
}

class ChildA extends Parent {
  bar: string;
}

class ChildB extends Parent {
  baz: string
}
```

In this setting,

```js
const a = new ChildA({ foo: 'foo', bar: 'bar'});
```

gives the following error.

```
TS2345: Argument of type '{ foo: string; bar: string }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Partial<Parent>'.
Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'bar' does not exist in type 'Partial<Parent>'.
```

`constructor<T extends Parent>(v: Partial<T>)` does not work neither. (TS1092: Type parameters cannot appear on a constructor declaration.)

Can I define constructor of classes Parent, ChildA and ChildB in type safe way?

Comment: Hmm, without something like [microsoft/TypeScript#38038](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38038) I think the closest you'll get here is explicit F-bounded polymorphism like [this code](https://tsplay.dev/W4pYAW).  If that works for you I'm happy to write up an answer; if it doesn't, please [edit] the question to show use cases where this solution does not work.

Comment: This is what I looked for. I use this as `Parent<T extends Parent<T> = any>` for compatibility and simplicity. Does setting any to default cause any typing issue?

Comment: You could use `any`, or `Parent<any>`, or `Parent<Parent<any>>`, or even the "correct" version like `type ParentItself = Parent<ParentItself>`.  But whether any of those cause typing issues depends on your use cases and what else depends on `T`.  I suppose as long as only the constructor depends on `T`, and whenever you subclass `Parent` you write  `class X extends Parent<X>` instead of `class X extends Parent` then there won't be an issue.  I will write up an answer when I get a chance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use [the polymorphic `this` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#this-types) inside constructor parameters.

Unfortunately, this is explicitly not supported; see [microsoft/TypeScript#5449](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5449), especially [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5449#issuecomment-152553432), and a related feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#5863](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5863).  There's a relatively recent feature request to allow `this` in constructor parameters at [microsoft/TypeScript#40451](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/40451). For now, then, there's no simple way to tell the compiler that you want the constructor parameter to depend on the type of the "current" class constructor (and thus be inherited by subclasses).

If you want this sort of behavior then, you're not going to get it for free from TypeScript; you'll have to work around it.

---

Polymorphic-`this` is a type of "implicit" [F-bounded polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_quantification#F-bounded_quantification), meaning that you can think of `this` being like a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter which is [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to itself.  Since we can't have the implicit version for constructor parameters, maybe we can do it *explicitly* by adding a self-bounded type parameter to the class:

```
abstract class Parent<T extends Parent<T>> {
    public foo: string = "";

    constructor(v: Partial<T>) {
        Object.assign(this, v);
    }
}
```

That works; note how in `Parent<T>`, the type parameter `T` is constrained to `Parent<T>` itself.  Now we can use `T` in lieu of the `this` type.  When we declare subclasses, we need to make this explicit:

```
class ChildA extends Parent<ChildA> {
    bar: string = "";
}

class ChildB extends Parent<ChildB> {
    baz: string = ""
}
```

And now your subclasses behave as desired:

```
new ChildA({ foo: 'foo', bar: 'bar' }).bar;
```

---

You mentioned that you might want to give `T` a [default](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) so that you can mention just `Parent` in other parts of your code.  For this default, you have a number of options, depending on how pedantic-vs-convenient you want to be.  The most convenient thing is `any`, the next-most pedantic thing is `Parent<any>`, followed by `Parent<Parent<any>>` (repeat as desired), followed by the extreme version:

```
type ParentItself = Parent<ParentItself>;
abstract class Parent<T extends Parent<T> = ParentItself> { /* ... */ }
```

Maybe you even want `never` as the default, which would probably highlight any accidental uses of `Parent` in places where it only makes sense to have a concrete subclass.  You would need to check these against your use cases to see which, if any, are suitable.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.2#code/C4TwDgpgBACghgJwgO2ASWAZwgGwGZQC8siKwAPPEqhtvgHwDcAUM3AEabAJwDGwUXjjiZMJahQAqUCAA9gKACZiqZcpPpFxZWrjyaA3sygmoYAK7scAS15Q8AewcAuKFwTXkAcy0AiXyzGprwOyO7m-A4IABQAbq5UwNZwOOr0AJRQRqY5UADy7ABWEPwAdCKY1l7I0cAAFtaYADRQseksOQC+zN3MQhVQAMINOIoAgjLySiqkqOTD1qNjhkEm7Iiu7p4+xP4svf2iQyOKAEKTCsjK2nMLo6crOesAXpvc236+PazIEADux0W42iBnsTlcAHJHA4IS11ghIfCIVBOulSvDGEA)

Answer (score 1):

I think the typescript error is correct

The `Parent` only exist `foo: string` variable

If you want to new `ChildA` you need to define construct in `ChildA` to correct the type passed from outside

```js
abstract class Parent {
    public foo: string;

    protected constructor(v: Partial<Parent>) {
        Object.assign(this, v);
    }
}

class ChildA extends Parent {
    bar: string;
    constructor(v: Partial<ChildA>) {
        super(v);
    }
}


const a = new ChildA({ foo: 'foo', bar: 'bar'});
```